# Swiper 3.4.2 initialslide: 0 or mySwiper.slideTo(0) not working like expected

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have a problem with Swiper 3.4.2 `initialslide: 0` or `mySwiper.slideTo(0)`.

I open a popup and parse the clicked item (itemindex),
now the swiper is initialiced and opens with correct slide.
Except, when its the first slide (itemindex is 0) if this is the case, the last slide is visible, not the slide with index = 0,

```
function testswiperpopup(itemidndex) {
        var popupswiper = new Swiper('.swiper-popup-container', {
            initialSlide: itemidndex,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            lazyLoading: true,
            lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
            lazyLoadingInPrevNextAmount: 1,
            spaceBetween: 60,
            keyboardControl: true,
            nextButton: '.test-swiper-next',
            prevButton: '.test-swiper-prev'
        });
        popupswiper.slideTo(itemidndex,0,false);
    }
```

I tried both methods initialSlide and slideTo.

Does anybody has an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i made it work like this:

```
    var popupswiper = new Swiper('.swiper-popup-container', {
        initialSlide: itemidndex,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        lazyLoading: true,
        lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
        lazyLoadingInPrevNextAmount: 1,
        spaceBetween: 60,
        keyboardControl: true,
        nextButton: '.test-swiper-next',
        prevButton: '.test-swiper-prev'
    });

    popupswiper.setWrapperTranslate(0);
    popupswiper.slideTo(itemidndex,0,false);
}
```

but its a little strange that you can `slideTo(x)` or set `initialSlide: x` any swipe except the first one